# how execute php file in a browser with eclipse

Tags: php, phpeclipse

I need to execute php file in a web browser. I use eclipse that is just configured for php. My code is very simply:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='hi'>Hello</a>";
```

I start with "PHP Web Application" but I obtain is:

http://it.tinypic.com/r/24pjwq9/8

> "Object don't find".

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You are either using the wrong URL for the ressource, or you don't have the correct file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **wrong URL**.

For the moment if you just need to test your script then it's not that hard with the new *PHP's inbuilt web server*

1. Goto the folder where you have the php file from command prompt.
2. Type `php -S localhost:8000` and start the php web server *(As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.)*
3. Lets say your file name is `index.php`. Then goto the web browser and type http://localhost:8000/index.php